# How can I kill a process that restart itself each time on Mac?

Tags: macos, port

I need to use the port 5000 with flask but it seems to be already in use by some process.

This is my output when I run `sudo lsof -i:5000`:

`COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME`

`ControlCe 1897 manu   32u  IPv4 0x4ab7b80aa5149af7      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)`

`ControlCe 1897 manu   32u  IPv4 0x4ab7b80aa5149af7      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)`

Whenever I try to kill the process by running `kill -9 $PID` it restarts immediately.

I don't know what this process is and why is occupying the port 5000.

Of course I could set flask to use another port but I would really like to know what this process is and why I can't kill it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

macOS Monterey has a new feature called "AirPlay Receiver" that uses port 5000. You can disable this feature in System Preferences -> Sharing -> AirPlay Receiver. After this, you should find port 5000 free again.

Comment: yup confirmed. RIP to running flask on port 5000 on Monterey.