# Error: That Port is already in use (Heroku/Django)

Tags: django, heroku

When I run `heroku local` on my machine I get the following error:

```
07:44:21 web.1   |  Watching for file changes with StatReloader
07:44:22 web.1   |  Error: That port is already in use.
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
07:44:22 web.1   Exited with exit code null
```

When I run `sudo lsof -i tcp:5000` This is what I see:

```
COMMAND     PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ControlCe 83303    x    19u  IPv4 0x874167a5a53a48c7      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
ControlCe 83303    x    20u  IPv6 0x874167a5922f00af      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
```

I've tried to kill the above processes using `kill -9`  but they don't seem to go away - I'm not sure if these are what are causing the issue either.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: How would I check this? As far as I can see I don't

Comment: Actually, this looks like a macOS thing. Have you already configured Django to respect the `PORT` environment variable? Do you have a `Procfile`?

Comment: I do here is the Procfile contents: ``web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT``

Comment: And are you setting a `PORT` environment variable on your development machine, e.g. via `PORT=5000` in a `.env` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It looks like port 5000 is used by "AirPlay Receiver" on macOS Monterey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69736492/354577). The answer on that question shows how you can disable AirPlay Receiver in your System Preferences.

But if you don't want to disable that feature you could also just use a different port. Django's default development port is 8000, so that might be a good choice.

Assuming you have something like this in your `.env` file:

```
PORT=5000
```

simply change it to

```
PORT=8000
```